# How to remove dashed line around WPF control when focused

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

About a few days ago, we ran our WPF application, some of us(in several developer's computers) found very a lot controls has dashed border when they got focused, such as below:

[image: Capture]

The outer control is `Grid`, and in other place, `Border` and others also has same issue.

And in the past days, it's gone. Today, all of our team can see this issue.

We tried to set the element `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"`, it has no effect at all, and we couldn't find what changes affected it.

So, does this issue related to the computer environment? And what possible reason can cause this strange issue?

**Updated:**

We just tried our application in a clean virtual machine, it can be reproduced, so maybe the only point of this issue is our code.

Since we haven't found the related code caused this issue, we didn't know upload what XAML code to show this issue.

Comment: Have you checked the `ShowGridLines` property? I've never seen such thing before in our WPF projects.

Comment: I think you should try to reproduce issue in a clean sample. If you can reproduce it, give us the xaml and we can figure out what's going on beyond a tabstop & focus visual.

Comment: @Bolu yeah, I just tried, and it didn't work...

Comment: @Maverik YEAH. i also wish that, but I cannot give you all the xaml, or the related part code which we might found the cause if we know the related stuff :)

Comment: @Bolu Have you tried the Windows button, if it got focus, it has dashed border around.  BTW, I use Windows 7. So maybe it's a Windows setting?

Comment: No, I don't have that effect on my machine (Win7 too), you are probably right, could be a Windows setting.

Answer (score 15):

Since `FocusVisualStyle` does not support converting from string, these two options both worked for me:

```
<Grid FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" />
```

Or

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.FocusVisualStyle>
        <Style />
    </Grid.FocusVisualStyle>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this won't be of much use to the OP but in case anyone else is struggling with issue...

I strongly suspect setting FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" is the answer but sometimes it may not be obvious which control(s?) in the visual tree to set it on. I suggest using [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), snoop the application, enable the preview, expand the preview area, recreate the issue in snoop by clicking on the visual tree then re-selecting the problem area in your application like so:

[image]

Then try deleting the FocusVisualStyle by simply clicking on the Value (in yellow in my screenshot) and deleting. Rinse and repeat until you find the culprit(s). The visual tree tree probably won't quite match the logical tree but through trial and error you work it out.

In my example above I found it was the ScrollViewer causing my annoying dotted rectangle rather than the canvas that I first assumed it would be.

Regards David

Answer (score 1):

Setting [`IsTabStop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.istabstop.aspx) to `false` on those controls should resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the FocusVisualStyle Property to none.

Comment: OP state in the question: `We tried to set the element FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}", it has no effect at all`